# Calculating time of custom timer job execution in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-timer-job

I have written a custom timer job for prOcessing few number of doc libs and few splists in my site collection and apply item level permissions for the items matching some criteria through CAML query.
Now, for checking the functionality, i want to see how much time its taking to enumerate these splists/spdoc libs inside this timer job. ie,to calculate the actual time of execution for this timer job.

Is there a  way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could write some timestamps at the beginning and the end of processing to either:

- the ULS log or,
- a database.

Writing to the ULS log can be done like this:
https://bipinpankhania.wordpress.com/2015/06/25/write-to-uls-logs-programmatically-in-sharepoint-2013sharepoint-2010-on-premise/amp/